# pyserial: I received that I send

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm tried to get the answer from a machine throught serial's com.
but i dont why i am receiving that i send!

```
with serial.Serial(port,
                       baudrate=9600,
                       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                       parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                       #timeout=0.5,
                       xonxoff=False,
                       rtscts=False,
                       dsrdtr=False
                       ) as ser:
        print(port,'opened!')

        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        o1='at+cgmr\r\n'
        x=ser.write(o1.encode()) #without encode() error!
        print('sended',x,'bytes','-->',o1)
        sleep(1)
        y=ser.readline(10) #ser.readline() is the same and read(10) as well

        print('answer',y)
```

And the output is:

```
COM3 opened!

sended 8 bytes --> at+cgmr

respuesta b'at+cgmr\r\r\n'
```

Teorically i have to receive 'ok' or 'not ok'.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the device echoes back what it got and then sends its reply. Have you tried to increase the number of bytes you receive?

There is a chance that if you do `y = ser.read(100)` (with timeout enabled), you will get everything you asked for.

An alternative is to read exactly as many bytes as there are available:

```
y = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
```

or

```
y = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
```

(depending on the version of pyserial).

Comment: you are my personal Jesus. you wil be in my prayers from now ;-)

Comment: @donostialdea An upvote in addition to the accept you already gave me would be more helpful :-D